# Unpermitted params :video when uploading video [paperclip]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, video, paperclip

I got `Unpermitted parameter: video` today, my model:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Extends

  # Includes

  # Associations
  belongs_to :videoable, polymorphic: true

  has_attached_file :video
  validates_attachment_content_type :video, content_type: /\Avideo\/.*\Z/
  validates_attachment_file_name :video, :matches => [/3gp\Z/, /mp4\Z/, /flv\Z/]
end
```

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :videos, as: :videoable

  # accepts_nested_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :videos
end
```

the controller:

```
params.require(:campaign).permit(videos_attributes: [:video, :video_file_name, :id, :_destroy])
```

the view:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :videos, Video.new do |v|
       = v.file_field :video, multiple: true
= f.simple_fields_for :videos do |v|
       = video_tag(v.object.video.url, controls: true, size: "148x148") if v.object.video?
       br
       .form-inline
          = v.check_box :_destroy, class: 'form-control'
              | Delete
```

not sure what was I missed in this case, I tried to google it but result is the same as my setting up, appreciate all your suggestion, thanks
*I'm using paperclip to support uploading file*

params request:

```
"videos_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"video"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f5bcfad6f88 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190201-6213-waz9el.mp4>, @original_filename="facebook_user_link.mp4", @content_type="video/mp4", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"campaign[videos_attributes][0][video][]\"; filename=\"facebook_user_link.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n">], "_destroy"=>"0"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the issue, in the view I set:
`= v.file_field :video, multiple: true`
so I need to set the params for video like this:
`params.require(:campaign).permit(videos_attributes: [:video_file_name, :id, :_destroy, video: []])`
then the uploading process will work correctly.